# Table headers inside main table header in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

How can I achieve this kind of table:

[image]

Inside the Schedule column, there are sub columns (Jan, Feb and so on).

I tried `<th></th>` inside a `<th></th>`

But it is not working.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TAJzY/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The solution is `colspan=""` and `rowspan=""`:

  - Use `colspan="12"` on the "Schedule/Milestone of Activities" cell.

    - And remove the 12 empty trailing cells in the same `<tr>` row.
  - Use `rowspan="2"` on the "Estimated Budget" cell.

    - And remove the single empty initial `<th>` cell from the `<tr>` below.
- Don't forget to use explicit `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and optional `<tfoot>` sections.

  - While you *can* use HTML tables without explicit sections, styling HTML tables with CSS is a lot easier and effective this way, and you can use techniques like `thead { position: sticky; }` for Excel-style "frozen" rows which are otherwise very difficult - or just tedious - to implement otherwise.

---

#### Step 1:

First, make a table, without any splitting/merging of cells, so you have something like this (click the "Run code snippet" button below to see the table):

```css
table { border: 1px outset #bbb; }
table > * > tr > * { border: 1px inset #bbb; }

thead { background-color: #7ACABD; text-align: center; }
tbody { background-color: #e0fffa; }
tfoot { background-color: #39c4ae' }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Estimated Budget</th>
            <th>Schedule/Milestone of Activities</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Jan</th>
            <th>Feb</th>
            <th>Mar</th>
            <th>Apr</th>
            <th>May</th>
            <th>Jun</th>
            <th>Jul</th>
            <th>Aug</th>
            <th>Sep</th>
            <th>Oct</th>
            <th>Nov</th>
            <th>Dec</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>$123</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td>o</td>
            <td>n</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>$456</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td>o</td>
            <td>n</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

#### Step 2:

Then make the "Schedule/Milestone of Activities" cell span all 12 remaining columns (of the 13 total) with `colspan="12"` - which also means removing the empty trailing `<th></th>` elements in the same `<tr>` as those are now represented by the `<th colspan="12">` cell:

```css
table { border: 1px outset #bbb; }
table > * > tr > * { border: 1px inset #bbb; }

thead { background-color: #7ACABD; }
tbody { background-color: #e0fffa; }
tfoot { background-color: #39c4ae' }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Estimated Budget</th>
            <th colspan="12">Schedule/Milestone of Activities</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Jan</th>
            <th>Feb</th>
            <th>Mar</th>
            <th>Apr</th>
            <th>May</th>
            <th>Jun</th>
            <th>Jul</th>
            <th>Aug</th>
            <th>Sep</th>
            <th>Oct</th>
            <th>Nov</th>
            <th>Dec</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>$123</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td>o</td>
            <td>n</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>$456</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td>o</td>
            <td>n</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

#### Step 3:

To make the "Estimated Budget" cell span those 2 rows in `<thead>` add `rowspan="2"` and also remove the empty initial `<th></th>` in the second `<tr>` (as that empty `<th>` cell's "slot" is now taken by the `<th rowspan="2">` from the previous row).

Like so:

```css
table { border: 1px outset #bbb; }
table > * > tr > * { border: 1px inset #bbb; }

thead { background-color: #7ACABD; }
tbody { background-color: #e0fffa; }
tfoot { background-color: #39c4ae; }

/* Right-align budget numbers in the first column: */
table > tbody > tr > td:first-child { text-align: right; }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Estimated Budget</th>
            <th colspan="12">Schedule/Milestone of Activities</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Jan</th>
            <th>Feb</th>
            <th>Mar</th>
            <th>Apr</th>
            <th>May</th>
            <th>Jun</th>
            <th>Jul</th>
            <th>Aug</th>
            <th>Sep</th>
            <th>Oct</th>
            <th>Nov</th>
            <th>Dec</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>$123</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td>o</td>
            <td>n</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>$456</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>m</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>j</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td>o</td>
            <td>n</td>
            <td>d</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sorry if im too noob about html wahahaha i forgot the past knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You use the `colspan` attribute on the Schedule `th`. It would make it to span over many columns.

Using `rowspan` for the Budget `th` will have the same effect on rows.

Comment: I think you mean "span over many columns", not rows. Also, don't forget `rowspan` for the "Estimated budget" cell too.

Comment: @shnisaka an anime fan are we? Come over to [anime.se], we need you there

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note use of colspan):

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>budget</td>
    <td colspan="3">header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use my http://blocknote.net editor if you need more complex table layout. Table editor there is pretty convenient.

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td colspan="3">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Content</td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo1</td>
    <td>foo2</td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<th>` cannot contain other `<th>` elements. You're also missing your opening `<tbody>` element.